# Extracting the initCover function

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I was given these instructions:

I need to do this.

1. Cut out the `initCover` function
2. Write `initCover` where the function used to be
3. Paste the `initCover` function above the `videoPlayer.init` code.

How is this done?

```
videoPlayer.init({
  afterPlayerReady: function initCover() {
    manageCover.init(function playVideo() {
      videoPlayer.play();
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is, (are you getting any **error** message?)...

```
//# Cut out the "initCover" function
//# Paste the "initCover" function above the "videoPlayer.init" code.
function initCover()
{
    manageCover.init(   
                        function playVideo() 
                        { 
                            videoPlayer.play(); 
                        }
                    );
}

//# Write "initCover" where the function used to be
videoPlayer.init( initCover() ); //# eg: run initCover function from here
```